# Copy/paste highlighted text into new different documents

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy-paste, highlight

I use Word documents which are highlighted in a number of colors. What I need is for the VBA to find a highlighted section and paste that text in a new document, find the next highlighted section in a different color and copy that text in a new (different) document). My code does that for all 15 colors available for highlighting in Word. However, even if the color is not present in the text, it will create a new document for that color. So every time I run my code, I get 15 new documents.

I need the code to ignore a highlight color if that color is not present, while still creating new (and different) documents for the colors that are present in the document.

For example, I might get a document that only has highlighted text in blue and green, so I would need two new documents for that. Or I might get a document that has highlighted text in blue, green, yellow and red, so I would need four new focuments, one for each color.

Any ideas on what I need to change?

```
Sub ExtractHighlightedTextsInSameColor()
Dim objDoc As Document, objDocAdd As Document
Dim objRange As Range
Dim strFindColor As String
Dim highliteColor As Variant
Dim i As Long

highliteColor = Array(wdYellow, wdBlack, wdBlue, wdBrightGreen, wdDarkBlue, wdDarkRed, wdDarkYellow, wdGreen, wdPink, wdRed, wdTeal, wdTurquoise, wdViolet, wdWhite)

Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
For i = LBound(highliteColor) To UBound(highliteColor)
    Set objDocAdd = Documents.Add
    Set objRange = objDocAdd.Content
    objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    objDoc.Activate
    Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Format = True
        .Highlight = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
        Do While .Found
            If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = highliteColor(i) Then
            ' the following copies only the highlighted text
                objRange.FormattedText = Selection.Range.FormattedText
            'if you want the entire paragraph that contains a highlighted text item then use this
            '    objRange.FormattedText = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.FormattedText
                Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEndwdYellow
                objRange.InsertParagraphAfter
                objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Else
                objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            End If
            .Execute
        Loop
    End With
    objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    If i < UBound(highliteColor) Then
        'added a conditional check so an extra page break is not inserted at end of document
        objRange.InsertBreak Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier to manage if you split your code up a bit: first collect all of the highlighted ranges, and then process them.

This should be pretty close.

```vb
Sub TestDoc()
    
    Dim col As Collection, rng As Range, dict As Object, hc As String
    Dim doc As Document, destRng As Range
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") 'for tracking documents vs highlight colors
    
    Set col = HighlightedRanges(ActiveDocument)     'first get all highlighted ranges
    For Each rng In col
        hc = CStr(rng.HighlightColorInde     'get the highlight color
        If Not dict.Exists(hc) Then          'need a new doc for this one?
            dict.Add hc, Documents.Add       'add doc and key to highlight color
        End If
        Set doc = dict(hc)                   'get doc for this color
        Set destRng = doc.Content            'copy the content over...
        destRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        destRng.InsertParagraphAfter
        destRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        destRng.FormattedText = rng.FormattedText
    Next rng
End Sub


'return a collection of all highlighted ranges in `doc`
Function HighlightedRanges(doc As Document) As Collection
    Dim rng As Range, col As New Collection
    Set rng = doc.Content
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Format = True
        .Highlight = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        Do While .Execute
            col.Add doc.Range(rng.Start, rng.End) 'clone the range
        Loop
    End With
    Set HighlightedRanges = col  'return all the found ranges
End Function
```